# TensorFlow with keras: Where is the ReLU layer in tf version 1.8?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, relu

Update: Found it: The class is [tf.keras.layers.Activation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Activation#__init__); needs to be called with argument activation='relu'....

---

Trying to access tf.keras.layers.ReLU gives the error:

> AttributeError: module
>   'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.keras.layers' has no attribute
>   'ReLU'.

In the docs, version [master](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ReLU) has such a layer. Version 1.8 (and 1.9) only seems to have leaky relu, PReLU, and other derivatives.

Right now I'm using [ThresholdedReLU](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ThresholdedReLU) with theta of 0.0, I hope this results in a standard ReLU. But there must be a simple 'ReLU' layer as well?

Where can I find keras' ReLU layer in tensorflow 1.8?
I want a keras layer class, i.e., not [tf.keras.backend.relu](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/relu).

It feels as if I'm overlooking something completely obvious. I haven't used keras before, so, sorry if this is a super stupid question.

Comment: I think you can keep the question, can you tell where this is documented? My answer below is also not relevant as its tf api for 1.9 while you are looking for 1.8

Comment: It's linked now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple activation layers you can just use the Activation layer.

```
Activation('relu')
```

[Available activations can be found here](https://keras.io/activations/)

Comment: link is broken, it's probably this: https://keras.io/activations/#available-activations